# Bokeh patches not loading multipolygons with CDS

Tags: python, gis, bokeh, geojson, patch

I would like to use CDS(ColumnDataSource) as I will update the map with a slider, I KNOW that I could use GeoJsonDataSource and also that it would be possible to update it with geojson, although I will embed it to a webapp and geojson will be extremely heavy on it, despite I rather to work with CDS because I have more control about the whole lot.
Also is there another way to get the 'geometry' column without dissolve it(a lot memory involved)?
So when it is a multipolygon the patches won't load it, which will give me just the simple polygons. If someone could help me out.
Thanks in advance!
The data is available here [scroll down and select  2008 Local Electoral Areas](https://www.cso.ie/en/census/census2011boundaryfiles/)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
from bokeh.io import (output_notebook, show, curdoc, output_file)
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import GeoJSONDataSource, LinearColorMapper, ColorBar, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.glyphs import MultiPolygons
from copy import deepcopy
from bokeh.palettes import Pastel2, viridis, inferno, magma, Paired, Spectral, brewer, Greens, YlGn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
output_notebook()

geoIrl = gpd.read_file('Census2011_Local_Electoral_Areas_2008.shp')
irlg = geoIrl[['COUNTY','geometry']]
irl = irlg.dissolve(by='COUNTY', aggfunc='sum')
dfirl = deepcopy(irl)


#extracting the xs and ys
def getPolyCoords(row, geom, coord_type):
    """Returns the coordinates ('x|y') of edges/vertices of a Polygon/others"""

    # Parse the geometries and grab the coordinate
    geometry = row[geom]
    #print(geometry.type)

    if geometry.type=='Polygon':
        if coord_type == 'x':
            # Get the x coordinates of the exterior
            # Interior is more complex: xxx.interiors[0].coords.xy[0]
            return list( geometry.exterior.coords.xy[0] )
        elif coord_type == 'y':
            # Get the y coordinates of the exterior
            return list( geometry.exterior.coords.xy[1] )

    if geometry.type in ['Point', 'LineString']:
        if coord_type == 'x':
            return list( geometry.xy[0] )
        elif coord_type == 'y':
            return list( geometry.xy[1] )

    if geometry.type=='MultiLineString':
        all_xy = []
        for ea in geometry:
            if coord_type == 'x':
                all_xy.append(list( ea.xy[0] ))
            elif coord_type == 'y':
                all_xy.append(list( ea.xy[1] ))
        return all_xy

    if geometry.type=='MultiPolygon':
        all_xy = []
        for ea in geometry:
            if coord_type == 'x':
                all_xy.append(list( ea.exterior.coords.xy[0] ))
            elif coord_type == 'y':
                all_xy.append(list( ea.exterior.coords.xy[1] ))
        return all_xy

    else:
        # Finally, return empty list for unknown geometries
        return []

dfirl['xs'] = dfirl.apply(getPolyCoords, geom='geometry', coord_type='x', axis=1)
dfirl['ys'] = dfirl.apply(getPolyCoords, geom='geometry', coord_type='y', axis=1)

rX = 'CARLOW', 'CAVAN', 'CLARE', 'CORK', 'DONEGAL', 'DUBLIN', 'GALWAY','KERRY', 'KILDARE', 'KILKENNY', 'LAOIS', 'LEITRIM', 'LIMERICK','LONGFORD', 'LOUTH', 'MAYO', 'MEATH', 'MONAGHAN', 'OFFALY', 'ROSCOMMON', 'SLIGO', 'TIPPERARY', 'WATERFORD', 'WESTMEATH', 'WEXFORD', 'WICKLOW'
srcmap = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=rX, y02=df_map['2002'], y06=df_map['2006'], y11=df_map['2011'], y16=df_map['2016'], xs=df_map['xs'], ys=df_map['ys']))

pc = figure(title = 'test', tools = '', x_axis_location = None, y_axis_location = None)

pc.patches('xs', 'ys', fill_alpha = 0.7, line_width = 0.5, source = srcmap)
#pc.grid.grid_line_color=None
show(pc)
```

If I select a multipolygon individually I will be able to plot it, using patches.

```
xstest =df_map.loc['DUBLIN']['xs']
ystest = df_map.loc['DUBLIN']['ys']
pc = figure(title = 'test', tools = '', x_axis_location = None, y_axis_location = None)
pc.patches(xs=xstest, ys=ystest, fill_alpha = 0.7, line_width = 0.5)
show(pc)
```

[image: geojson]
[image: xs_ys_CDS]
[image: individually]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this answers your question exactly.  But maybe it'll help.  I wrote the following to deconstruct a GeoPandas data frame and use `multi_polygons` to display the data in Bokeh.  I feed this function with MultiPolygon elements of geometries from GeoPandas.

```py
def get_MultiPoly(mpoly,coord_type='x'):
    """Returns the coordinates ('x' or 'y') for the exterior and interior of MultiPolygon digestible by multi_polygons in Bokeh"""
    
    if coord_type == 'x':
        i=0
    elif coord_type == 'y':
        i=1
    
    # Get the x or y coordinates
    c = [] 
    if isinstance(mpoly,Polygon):
        mpoly = [mpoly]
    for poly in mpoly: # the polygon objects return arrays, it's important they be lists or Bokeh fails
        exterior_coords = poly.exterior.coords.xy[i].tolist();
        
        interior_coords = []
        for interior in poly.interiors:
            if isinstance(interior.coords.xy[i],list):
                interior_coords += [interior.coords.xy[i]];
            else:
                interior_coords += [interior.coords.xy[i].tolist()];
        c.append([exterior_coords, *interior_coords])
    return c
```

The following is a full example given a dataset from https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/

(The .html file will be huge, about 20MB, because it's drawing the whole world in relatively high res, just set a small number for N to draw fewer countries faster)

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon
from shapely.geometry.multipolygon import MultiPolygon
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.models import  MultiPolygons, ColorMapper, LinearColorMapper
from bokeh.palettes import Inferno256 as palette
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.layouts import row, column

# Define the function I gave earlier
def get_MultiPoly(mpoly,coord_type='x'):
    """Returns the coordinates ('x' or 'y') for the exterior and interior of MultiPolygon digestible by multi_polygons in Bokeh"""
    
    if coord_type == 'x':
        i=0
    elif coord_type == 'y':
        i=1
    
    # Get the x or y coordinates
    c = [] 
    if isinstance(mpoly,Polygon):
        mpoly = [mpoly]
    for poly in mpoly: # the polygon objects return arrays, it's important they be lists or Bokeh fails
        exterior_coords = poly.exterior.coords.xy[i].tolist();
        
        interior_coords = []
        for interior in poly.interiors:
            if isinstance(interior.coords.xy[i],list):
                interior_coords += [interior.coords.xy[i]];
            else:
                interior_coords += [interior.coords.xy[i].tolist()];
        c.append([exterior_coords, *interior_coords])
    return c

# Define input/output files and get data, index by name
output_file("tmp.html")

map_world_gpd = gpd.read_file('map_data/ne_10m_admin_0_countries/ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp')
map_world_gpd.set_index('NAME_EN',inplace=True)

# Parse all countries into a ColumnDataSource
N=len(map_world_gpd) 
source3 = ColumnDataSource({ 
    'x': [get_MultiPoly(map_world_gpd.iloc[i]['geometry'],'x') for i in range(0,N)],
    'y': [get_MultiPoly(map_world_gpd.iloc[i]['geometry'],'y') for i in range(0,N)],
    'n': [i for i in range(0,N)],
    'name':[map_world_gpd.iloc[i]['NAME'] for i in range(0,N)],
    })

# Plot all the countries
p = figure(title="map_exploration",match_aspect=True,aspect_ratio=2,
            tooltips=[
                ("Name",'@name')
                ],
            )

p.multi_polygons(xs='x',ys='y', source=source3,
          fill_color={'field': 'n', 'transform': LinearColorMapper(palette=palette,low=0,high=len(source3.data['x']))},
          fill_alpha=0.5, line_color="black", line_width=0.5)

show(row(p,sizing_mode = 'scale_width'))
```

Here is another much simpler example to illustrate the differences:

```py
from bokeh.io       import show, output_file
from bokeh.models   import ColumnDataSource, MultiPolygons
from bokeh.models   import ColorMapper, LinearColorMapper 
from bokeh.palettes import Turbo256 as palette
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.layouts  import row, column

output_file("tmp.html")

xs = [[0, 0, 1, 1, 0], [1.5, 1.5, 2.5, 2.5, 1.5], [3, 3, 4, 4, 3]]
ys = [[0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0]]

xs_nan = [[*xs[0],float('NaN'),*xs[1],float('NaN'),*xs[2]]]
ys_nan = [[*ys[0],float('NaN'),*ys[1],float('NaN'),*ys[2]]]

xs_mp =  [[[x] for x in xs]]
ys_mp =  [[[y] for y in ys]]

# Make data for a patch for each polygon in a Multipolygon, all different colors
source0 = ColumnDataSource({
    'x': xs,
    'y': ys,
    'color': list(range(0,len(xs))),
    })

# Make data for a patch for each polygon in a Multipolygon, all same color
source1 = ColumnDataSource({
    'x': xs,
    'y': ys,
    'color':[0]*len(xs),
    })

# Make data for a patch for each Multipolygon, separating polygons with nan 
source2 = ColumnDataSource({
    'x': xs_nan,
    'y': ys_nan,
    'color': [0],
    })
# Make data for Multipolygon, using one Multipolygon for all
source3 = ColumnDataSource({ 
    'x': xs_mp,
    'y': ys_mp,
    'color': [0],
    })

# Initialize our figures
p0 = figure(match_aspect=True,aspect_ratio=2,x_axis_location=None, y_axis_location=None,)
p1 = figure(match_aspect=True,aspect_ratio=2,x_axis_location=None, y_axis_location=None,)
p2 = figure(match_aspect=True,aspect_ratio=2,x_axis_location=None, y_axis_location=None,)
p3 = figure(match_aspect=True,aspect_ratio=2,x_axis_location=None, y_axis_location=None,)


# Plot 
p0.title.text = "Map has "+str(len(xs))+" polygons, patched using "+str(len(source1.data['x']))+" patches, different colors"
p0.patches('x', 'y', source=source0,
          fill_color={'field': 'color', 'transform': LinearColorMapper(palette=palette,low=0,high=len(xs))},
          fill_alpha=0.5, line_color="black", line_width=0.5)

p1.title.text = "Map has "+str(len(xs))+" polygons, patched using "+str(len(source1.data['x']))+" patches, same color"
p1.patches('x', 'y', source=source1,
          fill_color={'field': 'color', 'transform': LinearColorMapper(palette=palette,low=0,high=len(xs))},
          fill_alpha=0.5, line_color="black", line_width=0.5)

p2.title.text = "Map has "+str(len(xs))+" polygons, patched using "+str(len(source2.data['x']))+" patches using NaN separators (too dark, BUG)"
p2.patches('x', 'y', source=source2,
          fill_color={'field': 'color', 'transform': LinearColorMapper(palette=palette,low=0,high=len(xs))},
          fill_alpha=0.5, line_color="black", line_width=0.5)

p3.title.text = "Map has "+str(len(xs))+" polygons, using "+str(len(source3.data['x']))+" multipolygon, same color"
p3.multi_polygons(xs='x',ys='y', source=source3,
          fill_color={'field': 'color', 'transform': LinearColorMapper(palette=palette,low=0,high=len(xs))},
          fill_alpha=0.5, line_color="black", line_width=0.5)

show(column(p0,p1,p2,p3,sizing_mode = 'scale_width'))
```

Comment: Hi man @TheDrDos, welcome to the community. I believe that I figure a way around it after hours of research, I will take my time and go through your answer as soon as possible. Anyhow, thanks a lot for your answer and time.